# Rewriting Mixed effects model formula from R (lme4) to Julia

Tags: r, statistics, julia

I would like to get the same results in Julia as using lmer function from [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) library in R.
Please find below and example on a build-in mtcars dataset using R

```
library(lme4)
data<-mtcars    
data$vs<-as.factor(data$vs)
data$am<-as.factor(data$am)
data$gear<-as.factor(data$gear)
str(data)
model <- lmer(mpg ~ cyl:gear + hp:am + (1|gear:am), data = data)
```

I have found the `lmm()` function from [MixedModels](https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl) package for Julia which should be capable of running the same results, however I don't know how to rewrite the formula from the first argument of `lmer()` function using `lmm()`. Especially the interaction (:) operator.

I would be grateful for an answer with short example.

Comment: this might help https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl

Comment: The interaction operator is just `*` (this gives you main effects and interaction) or `&` (if you only want the interaction).

Answer (score 2):

The correspondence between R and Julia models here does not seem to be exact. There are also issues of different numerical algorithms. But my attempt to recreate the same model using `MixedModels` is as follows:

```
using RDatasets
using MixedModels

mtcars = dataset("datasets","mtcars")
mtcars[:AM] = PooledDataArray(mtcars[:AM])
mtcars[:Gear] = PooledDataArray(mtcars[:Gear])
mtcars[:GearAM] = PooledDataArray(collect(zip(mtcars[:Gear],mtcars[:AM])))
m = fit!(lmm(MPG ~ 1 + Gear + AM + Cyl + HP + (1|GearAM),mtcars))
```

Creating the mixed effect column manually is klunky - perhaps there is a better way. Note the differences in naming the coefficients between R and Julia. There are 6 fixed-effect coefficients in both.

The solution in Julia seems different (on my machine) but achieves a better log-likelihood. The random-effect is expected to be weak, as its variables are already present in the fixed-effects (it only accounts for dependence between Gear and AM), and there are only 32 data points.

Hope this helps and if you come up with a better understanding, it would be nice to add it in another answer or comment.

Comment: Do I need to convert it to PooledDataArray, or just to categorical?

Answer (score 2):

## Tl;DR

If you use `REML=true` and `@formula(MPG ~ 1 + Cyl & Gear + HP & AM + (1 | Gear & AM)` you can reproduce exactly.

## Longer answer

Support for `(1 | Gear & AM)` requires version 3 or higher of MixedModels.jl which as of now (August 2020) is unreleased, so to reproduce this you'll need to install it with `pkg"add MixedModels#master"`.  This was run on Julia 1.5.0:

```
using RDatasets, MixedModels
mtcars = RDatasets.dataset("datasets","mtcars")
categorical!(mtcars, [:AM, :Gear])
m = fit(MixedModel, 
        @formula(MPG ~ Cyl & Gear + HP & AM + (1 | Gear & AM)), 
        mtcars, 
        REML=true)
```

Produces this output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML
 MPG ~ 1 + Cyl & Gear + HP & AM + (1 | Gear & AM)
 REML criterion at convergence: 168.11435769585046

Variance components:
             Column    Variance  Std.Dev. 
Gear & AM (Intercept)  16.913543 4.1126078
Residual                7.988539 2.8264004
 Number of obs: 32; levels of grouping factors: 4

  Fixed-effects parameters:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                    Coef.  Std. Error      z  Pr(>|z|)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)    34.3507      3.50385     9.80    <1e-21
Cyl & Gear: 3  -1.08837     0.781649   -1.39    0.1638
Cyl & Gear: 4  -1.56833     0.875625   -1.79    0.0733
Cyl & Gear: 5  -0.167413    1.42839    -0.12    0.9067
HP & AM: 0     -0.0412826   0.0215381  -1.92    0.0553
HP & AM: 1     -0.0613247   0.0298067  -2.06    0.0396
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Compared with the R code you posted:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: mpg ~ cyl:gear + hp:am + (1 | gear:am)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 168.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.42280 -0.54922 -0.07898  0.54892  2.09217 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 gear:am  (Intercept) 16.914   4.113   
 Residual              7.989   2.826   
Number of obs: 32, groups:  gear:am, 4

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 34.35066    3.50385   9.804
cyl:gear3   -1.08837    0.78165  -1.392
cyl:gear4   -1.56833    0.87562  -1.791
cyl:gear5   -0.16741    1.42839  -0.117
hp:am0      -0.04128    0.02154  -1.917
hp:am1      -0.06132    0.02981  -2.057
```

### Without modifying data

You can also control which variables are treated as categorical by providing contrasts for them:

```
m2 = fit(MixedModel,
         @formula(MPG ~ Cyl & Gear + HP & AM + (1 | Gear & AM)),
         mtcars,
         REML=true,
         contrasts = Dict(:AM => DummyCoding(), :Gear => DummyCoding()))
```

## Explanation

There are two main differences in specifying the regression formula between R and Julia (with [StatsModels.jl](https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/stable/)).

1. In Julia, you use `&` to create an interaction between terms, but in R you use `:`.
2. In Julia, you have to explicitly say that you're defining a formula with the `@formula` macro.  In R, anything and everything is potentially a macro via the magic of "nonstandard evaluation".

So, the equivalent Julia formula for your model is

```
@formula(mpg ~ cyl&gear + hp&am + (1|gear&am))
```

For using `categorical!` to convert columns in a DataFrame to categorical, see the [DataFrames.jl docs](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/categorical/)